# ld warning in mac terminal using skm and c++ compiler

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I’ve been getting this warning when using the Mac terminal and skm library to compile a simple hello world program in C++. I’m new to this so not really sure what to do.

```
ld: warning: dylib (/Users/chriscommon/.splashkit/lib/macos/libSplashKit.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (10.15.4) than being linked (10.15)
ld: warning: object file (/Users/chriscommon/.splashkit/clang++/lib/macos/libSplashKitCpp.a(splashkit.cpp.o)) was built for newer macOS version (10.15.4) than being linked (10.15)
ld: warning: object file (/Users/chriscommon/.splashkit/clang++/lib/macos/libSplashKitCpp.a(adapter_type_mapper.cpp.o)) was built for newer macOS version (10.15.4) than being linked (10.15)
```

Does anyone know if there is some way I can resolve this so it links to the correct version? I’m running macOS10.15.7 and have tried to update skm, reinstall Xcode command line tools etc and the program works ultimately but the warnings appear each time I compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this flag to Xcode when you build your program:

```
-mmacosx-version-min=11.0
```